# Date to epoch conversion for regex group in perl one liner?

Tags: regex, perl

I have some csv data looking like this:

```
player A,1991,2006
player B,1958,1972
```

and I want to transform it to use epochs instead of years so that it looks like:

```
player A,1329638400,162008400
player B,1326389534,326359832
```

I'd prefer to use the following perl idiom:

```
cat player_data.csv | perl -pe 's{...}{...}g'
```

But trying to call the relevant perl function inside a regex I'm not experienced with.

Notes:

- I'm fine with hardcoding the month and day to something (preferably july 1st which is the start of new soccer seasons and I'm trying to capture data about their careers)

Comment: why use `cat` when you can pass the filename directly as argument to `perl`?

Comment: @spasic - "Make every program a filter" http://flylib.com/books/en/2.506.1.35/1/ . In other words, support reading input from stdin, so that you can compose them with pipes. I might want to do some transformation on my csv data before running the date conversion logic. I've omitted such logic in this example since it's not related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
perl -pe 'use Time::Local; s/(\d{4})/timelocal(0,0,0,1,0,$1)/ge' player_data.csv
```

Note this assumes that you want January 1st 00:00 in local time. If you want UTC instead, just use `timegm` instead of `timelocal`.

Comment: Thank you. Or as I prefer: `cat player_data.csv | perl -pe 'use Time::Local; s{(\d+)}{timelocal(0,0,0,1,0,$1)}ge'` . I'll mark correct as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: Or this one : `perl -MDateTime -pe 's/\d{4}/DateTime->new(year => $&)->epoch/ge' player_data.csv`

Comment: Yes `DateTime` makes it shorter, but `Time::Local` is a core module and comes with perl.

Comment: Yea that's why I post it as a comment and not an answer; yours get the job done without installing `DateTime`. But a question about date *needs* a `DateTime` answer, right? :)

Comment: Good to know both forms. Thanks.

Comment: In command-line programs, I like to use `-M` to load modules. `perl -MTime::Local -pe s/(\d{4})/timelocal(0,0,0,1,0,$1)/ge' player_data.csv`.